# Accessing static fields in XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml

How does one go about referencing a class's static properties in xaml?  In other words, I want to do something like this:

```
Class BaseThingy {
  public static readonly Style BaseStyle;
  ...
}
```

```
<ResoureDictionary ...>
  <Style BasedOn="BaseThingy.Style" TargetType="BaseThingy" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

What is the syntax to do this in the BasedOn?  I assumed it would involve using `StaticResource` to some degree, but I haven't gotten it to work for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [x:Static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx) markup extension

```
<ResoureDictionary ...
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Namespace.Where.Your.BaseThingy.Class.Is.Defined"
>
  <Style BasedOn="{x:Static local:BaseThingy.BaseStyle}" TargetType="BaseThingy" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: I was under the impression that `{x:Static ...}` doesn't work in Silverlight.

Comment: Is Namespace.Where.Your.BaseThingy.Class.Is.Defined the namespace of the class?