# What does "{x:Static}" mean in XAML?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

What does `{x:Static}` mean in XAML?

Code sample:

```
<SolidColorBrush Color="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlColor}" />
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It is a way to insert any static value into XAML. For example, if I have a class:

```
namespace A 
{ 
    public class MyConstants 
    {
        public static readonly string SomeConstantString = "BAM!";
    }
}
```

I can place it into a WPF UI using XAML like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static A:MyConstants.SomeConstantString}" />
```

Notice, you will have to import the namespace in which MyConstants is defined into your XAML. So in the  or  element do something like:

```
xmlns:A="clr-namespace:A"
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in Silverlight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373926/silverlight-4-equivalent-to-wpf-xstatic

Answer (score 6):

From MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx

References any static by-value code entity defined in a Common Language Specification (CLS) compliant way The property referenced is evaluated prior to loading the remainder of the XAML page and can be used to provide the value of a property in XAML.

Answer (score 0):

I found the question [XAML - Accessing static fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32395/xaml-accessing-static-fields) having an answer which links to the MSDN documentation [x:Static Markup Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx). I figured this would still be useful to have on the site.

Comment: Yeah, but a simple google search of "x:Static xaml" finds it too!

Comment: At the time I thought "search StackOverflow" not "search Google" and since I got my answer and wanted to get back to coding, I didn't bother to do a cross-reference with Google. I had the code and it worked—I was just curious what as to what it meant.

Comment: That brings up a good point. I wonder if a critical mass will be reached where stackoverflow becomes the first point of call rather than google for the majority of developers.

Comment: @AndrewRollings well, google search still seems much more functional. Otherwise I'd probably do just that. :)