# What does x:Static mean

Tags: wpf, xaml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “{x:Static}” mean in XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507942/what-does-xstatic-mean-in-xaml)

In a xaml file there is:

```
Command="{x:Static src:CustomCommands.Create}"
```

What does the x:Static mean? If I remove it then it throws an error when loading the xaml saying it "Cannot create unknown type CustomCommands.Create"

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507942/what-does-xstatic-mean-in-xaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx

The link above from MSDN mentions:

> References any static by-value code entity that is defined in a Common
>   Language Specification (CLS)–compliant way. The static property that
>   is referenced can be used to provide the value of a property in XAML.

Comment: I see. I was thinking it was two values "x:Static" and "src:CustomCommands.Create" but it is actually one value "x:Static src:CustomerCommands.Create".