# Using {x:Static} to access property of static field in a static class

Tags: c#, wpf

In WPF I'm trying to bind to a property of a readonly field in a static class,
I've already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507942/what-does-xstatic-mean-in-xaml) which will allow to bind to const string in a static class like this

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static A:MyConstants.SomeConstantString}" />
```

What I'm trying to do is like this

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static A:MyConstants.SomeReadOnlyField.StringProp}" />
```

but it gives me an error

> Nested types are not supported

Comment: You cant bind to **Fields** in WPF. Only on Properties

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provided that `SomeReadOnlyField` is a `public static readonly` field in class `MyConstants`, and that is has a public `StringProp` property, you could write your Binding like this:

```
Text="{Binding Path=StringProp
               Source={x:Static A:MyConstants.SomeReadOnlyField}}"
```

Note that while a Binding `Path` must resolve to the name of a public property, the `x:Static` markup extension used for the Binding `Source` can very well reference a static field.

Comment: Works Perfectly..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error means you cannot use a path to a value (stringprop) that is a value of a complex type (the readonlyfield).

the prop as in your first example, should be a property of MyConstants