# Where to set default values in a WPF C# app?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

Where would I set default values that I want to use throughout a project and only define once?

An example would be a default margin, or a color that I want to use in multiple places.

In pure C, one way to do this would be with a "defaults.h" header file with "#define"s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to store them in the application's resource dictionary, either in markup (in the `<Application.Resources>` element in `app.xaml`) or by creating them in code at startup and adding them to the resource dictionary.

This allows you to do some pretty sophisticated stuff fairly easily, so long as you have a consistent application-wide naming convention for resource keys.  For instance, it's easy to implement simple skinning in an application by building resource dictionaries in XAML files and then merging a specific dictionary into the application's dictionary at startup.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the appsettings section of an app.config file. See [here](http://www.tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=howtos&id=20) for more info.

Comment: What I really want is somewhat different from settings, I want to define static objects, that never change. Something like "Thickness DefaultUIMargin = new Thickness(5);"

Answer (score 1):

You can do most of this with resources and templates, if you want common looks and styles throughout your app.

**Edit**: Based on your comment, looking at x:Static may be what you're after.  [Here's a SO question covering it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32395/xaml-accessing-static-fields)  If that's still not quite it...try elaborating a bit more.

[This is what I first read when playing around with WPF explaining it.](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/wpf/StylesResourcesAndControlTemplatesInWPF.aspx)